# How to add pass username & password to proxy in selenium webdriver - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use luminati proxy here but stuck in an authentication, when I passed --proxy-server then it asks for password in a browser, I have tried to send username and password but not worked

sending username and password in proxy-server in this way giving an error as well

```
proxy-server=username:password@url:port
```

....

```rb
def build_driver
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: web_driver_options
end

def web_driver_options
  @web_driver_options ||= begin
                            options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
                            options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
                            options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
                            options.add_argument('--proxy-server=@zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225')
                            options
                          end
end
```

In puppeteer, there is a fix to this, but I searched a lot for selenium no answer found please help me here?

```
await page.authenticate({username: 'lum-customer-zone-residential-country-us', password: 'asasass'})
```

**Looking for a solution in selenium** puppeteer already working with this

Comment: This might be helpful: https://blog.apify.com/how-to-make-headless-chrome-and-puppeteer-use-a-proxy-server-with-authentication-249a21a79212

Comment: Hey I wanted to have it in selenium not in puppeteer its already working fine

Comment: @VishalG how did you solve it?